# Use a DbContext inside a Migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, psql

I want to use DbContext variable inside the Migration Up method.

I explain better my problem:
I have one migration done in this way

```
class Circle {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Radius {get; set;}
}

class Figure {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Circle> Circles {get; set;}
}

class GeometryDbContext: DbContext{
    public DbSet<Figure> Figures {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Figure>()
            .Property(e => e.Circles)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Circle>>(v) ?? new List<Circle()
            )
            .HasColumnName("Circles");
    }
}
```

In this way I have only one table named "Figures" which has a varchar column named "Circles", in which it's stored the stringified version of "Circles".

Now I want to updated it, in this way:

```
class Circle {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Radius {get; set;}

    public int IdFigure {get; set;}
        
    [ForeignKey(nameof(IdFigure))]
    public Figure? Figure {get; set;}
}

class Figure {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Circle> Circles {get; set;}
}

class GeometryDbContext: DbContext{
    public DbSet<Figure> Figures {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Circle> Circles {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }
}
```

In this way I have two tables linked by a foreign key.

How can I customize the Up method of the Migration class created, so that all data stored inside the "Circles" column pass in the "Circles" table?

P.S. I have a PSQL database, and I am using Entity Framework code-first

I tried using migrationBuilder.Sql to create a select query, but I found that you can't do it in a migration class.

I figured out I need to create a dbContext variable in the migration class in order to select data from a table.

Comment: [Custom migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations)

Comment: Migrations should NOT have any `DbContext` reference or connection to database. Use `migrationBuilder.Sql` only for this case. It is how they are designed.

Comment: Consider what would happen if you used the DbContext, but later add a migration to completely delete the figures table? Your migration would  fail to compile unless you had a complete copy of the DbContext and entities for each db version. This is most likely a case where you need to drop down to sql in one form or another.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv but I can't use migrationBuilder.Sql for a select query

Comment: You don't have to select anything, you have to use SQL to modify data. Or you can create temporary stored procedure then drop in another migration. Everything should be SQL, no materialization. Otherwise you have to invent your own logic how to apply custom migrations.

Comment: Ok, but how can I write one to solve my problem? I need to parse the data in the "Circles" column

Answer (score 0):

My solution to your problem is to adding another class named **Circle2**:

```
class Figure
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Circle> Circles {get; set;}
}

class Circle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Radius {get; set;}        
}

public class Circle2
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Radius { get; set; }
    public int FigureId { get; set; }
    public Figure Figure { get; set; }
}
```

and obviously another row DbSet:

```
DbSet<Circle2> Circle2s { get; set; }
```

to your DbContext also. And, after a migration that will add the new **Circle2** empty table to your database, you can execute, for one time only, this snippet of code:

```
foreach (var figure in db.Figures)
{
    foreach (var cir in figure.Circles)
    {
        Circle2 myCircle = new Circle2()
        {                
            Radius = cir.Radius,
            FigureId = figure.Id
        };
        db.Circle2s.Add(myCircle);
    }
}
                    
db.SaveChanges();
```

Doing so, you will populate the new **Circle2** table with all Circles of all Figures that you have in your **Figure** table, and you made a new **one-to-many** relationship also from Figures to Circle2s, in the correct way. You don't need to specify the foreign key and its name.

After that, if you want, I think you will need another migration, eliminating the old "Circles" columns (from Figures table) and its old relation in your OnModelCreating method.

N.B. The Ids on the new Circle2s table are "Autogenerating", so they are different values from the Figure.Circles collections old ones.

I tried it in LocalDb and it works.